# Boolean custom environemnt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed that boolean custom environment variable working in unexpected way in conditions. Without explicitly checking if it is true or false it's passing to `if` anyway.   ​

Example:
I had in `.env`

```
REACT_APP_TEST=false
```

when

```
(some stuff) 

if (process.env.TEST) { // getting here regardless of value
  yield call(fetchDocumentIfEnd, input)
}

if (process.env.TEST === true) { // working as expected
  yield call(fetchDocumentIfEnd, input)
}

(some stuff)
```

Why is working like that? I not found any information [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

React version: "^16.13.1"

Comment: `process.env.TEST` would evaluate to the *string* `"false"`, which (as a non-empty string) is truth-y. Note that `true !== "true"`, so `=== true` likely isn't what you want either.

Comment: You may write : `if (process.env.TEST === 'true') { .. } else { .. }`

Comment: Ahh.(i from strongly typed language, I must change way of thinking) Thanks for answers :)